# Disable next button while API data is fetching- DataGrid Material UI

Tags: reactjs, pagination, material-ui

I have a Material UI `<DataGrid />` component with server pagination.

The table shows 10 results and 10 more are fetched and shown whenever the next btn is pressed (if the already fetched results local array doesn’t have enough results already).

### Issue

The next btn is enabled even during API fetches, allowing the user to fetch more results even before the new results were loaded.

Is there a way to disable it while data is loading (i.e. when an `await` API request is still processing?

### Code reference

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
    
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import InfoOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/InfoOutlined';

import axios from 'axios';

export default function UsersView() {
  
  const [rowsState, setRowsState] = useState({
    page: 0,
    pageSize: 10,
    rows: [],
    loading: false,
  });
  const [allRows, setAllRows] = useState([]);

  const columns = [
    {
      field: 'picture',
      headerName: 'Picture',
      renderCell: (params) =>  <Avatar src={params.value.src} alt={params.value.alt} title={params.value.alt} />,
    },
    {
      field: 'fullName',
      headerName: 'Full name',
      width: 200
    },
    {
      field: 'email',
      headerName: 'Email',
      width: 250
    },
    {
      field: 'gender',
      headerName: 'Gender'
    },
    {
      field: 'age',
      headerName: 'Age'
    }
  ];
   
  useEffect(() => {
    
    let active = true;

    (async () => {
      try {
        const updatedAllRows = [...allRows];
        if (allRows.length <= rowsState.page * rowsState.pageSize) {
        setRowsState((prev) => ({ ...prev, loading: true }));
          const { data } = await axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10");

          if (!active) return;

          data.results.forEach(user => updatedAllRows.push(
            {
              id: user.login.uuid,
              picture: { src: user.picture.thumbnail, alt: `${user.name.title} ${user.name.first} ${user.name.last}` },
              fullName: `${user.name.title} ${user.name.first} ${user.name.last}`,
              email: user.email,
              gender: user.gender,
              age: user.gender
            }));
            setAllRows(updatedAllRows);
            console.log(updatedAllRows)
          }
          const pageRows = (updatedAllRows.slice(rowsState.page * rowsState.pageSize, (rowsState.page + 1) * rowsState.pageSize));
          setRowsState((prev) => ({ ...prev, loading: false, rows: pageRows }));
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    })();

    return () => {
      active = false;
    };
  }, [rowsState.page, rowsState.pageSize]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '95vh', width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        columns={columns}
        rowCount={100}
        {...rowsState}
        paginationMode="server"
        onPageChange={(page) => setRowsState((prev) => ({ ...prev, page }))}
        onPageSizeChange={(pageSize) => setRowsState((prev) => ({ ...prev, pageSize }))}
        pagination
        nextIconButtonProps={
          true &&
          {
            disabled: true
          }
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

As can be seen - I have tried (for testing) to disable the button via `nextIconButtonProps`, but I suspect it is deeply nested and hence does not have any effect.

How can I access the `disabled` option for the next button?

Comment: Please share some code to support your question.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a function that works when we click on the button, and the function should accept **event or e** as arguments, make sure to use **onClick** on the button.

if you try to console log the value of e you will find a

```
e.target.setAttribute
```

using which you can add attributes to the button this way which will make the button disabled whenever we click on it. **Remember to use *e* as an argument to function**

```
e.target.setAttribute("disabled", "true")
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! As you can see in the code, `<DataGrid/>` doesn't explicitly use a button component. The button comes with a pre-defined template for a pagination table. This is what causing the issue. I assume there is a specific tree of props that will lead me to the button options, but couldn't find the right path to it

Comment: Maybe you can just try to use an onClick attribute on the `<DataGrig />` and run a function using that. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I get the logic of what you're saying. Unfortunately it doesn't have any effect